# where is the 'googleBar' in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I write this in api v2:

`map.enableGoogleBar();`

I want to using v3, but I can't find `enableGoogleBar` function,

Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Bar does not currently exist in the Maps API v3. You can implement the functionality manually by performing a Local Search using the Google AJAX Search API's.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/local.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-v3-googlebar It approximates the search functionality of the GoogleBar in v2, but works in v3.

This project offers a couple of advantages over the previous suggestion:

It includes a custom wrapper for the LocalSearch API's RESTful side, allowing tighter integration with a v3 map than is possible with the regular AJAX APIs LocalSearch object

It also includes a custom SearchForm so that you don't have to load the Search API at all.

It should be noted, though, that it does NOT (yet?) support AdWords, like the original GoogleBar did.